# Set a variable value on click? + display the value?

Tags: jquery

how can I set a specific value on click?
For example:

```
 $("input[type='button']").click(function() {
   switch(this.id) {
     case 'ClickButtonOne': //VARIABLE1=something; break;
     case 'ClickButtonTwo': //VARIABLE1=something; break;
   }
 });
```

Then print the value somehow onto the screen. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $("input[type='button']").click(function() {
   var variable1 = 'default value'; // or add a default in the switch
   switch(this.id) {
     case 'ClickButtonOne':
         variable1 = 'something';
         break;
     case 'ClickButtonOne':
         variable1 = 'something else';
         break;
   }

   $('.the-element-you-want-to-add-it-to').html(variable1);
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

perhaps is possible set id to number/value:

```
   <html><head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function whichElement(e)
{
var targ;
if (!e)
  {
  var e=window.event;
  }
if (e.target)
  {
  targ=e.target;
  }
else if (e.srcElement)
  {
  targ=e.srcElement;
  }
if (targ.nodeType==3) // defeat Safari bug
  {
  targ = targ.parentNode;
  }

myVariable=targ.id;

alert("My variable is "+myVariable);
}
</script>
</head>

<body id="-1" onmousedown="whichElement(event)">

<p id="3.14">click here to set variable to 3.14</p>

<h3 id="5">click here to set variable to 5</h3>
<p id ="2">click here to set variable to 2</p>


</body></html>
```

other possibility is obtain number(value) from text/name of element (do not use id).

Answer (score 0):

make the variable global by defining it out of the scopes

```
var someVar = '';
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[type='button']").click(function() {
        switch(this.id) {
            case 'ClickButtonOne':
                someVar = 'something';
            break;
            case 'ClickButtonTwo':
                someVar='something else';
            break;
        }
        $("#someContainer").html(someVar);
    });
});
```

from what i understood (from the question), he wanted to set a variable which is already defined somewhere else. For this, it will have to be global. you can also store it in an HTML element using jquery (.data).
Normally what i do is create a javascript object that will contain relevant data. something like :

```
var someDataContainer = {
    somethingImportant : 5
};
```

and later on i could refer to it using someDataContainer.somethingImportant

Comment: Why would you want to make that variable global? Please don't suggest this when it is not needed.

Comment: Hmm, what are the roles of global and local variables in jquery?

Comment: @pufAmuf: Same as in other languages :) Using global vars when it is needed only clutters stuff and is most of the time definiatly not needed nor wanted.

Comment: Thank you :). I would like to use those variables later when sending them off to a php file to request data from a mysql database. Can they stay local for that? @Peeha & Galchen - Thanks for your contributions I really appreciate your time :)))

Comment: @pufAMuf: Well you can just grab the contents of the element you just filled with the data: `$('.the-element-you-want-to-add-it-to').html()` will now contain the data you want