# Click on text and set/define the text as value of javascript variable

Tags: javascript

Example is based on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/7132830/2465936

Here is working example http://jsfiddle.net/rigaconnect/aGWGn/3/

If click on `<p id ="2310">click here to set variable to 2310</p>`

then in `<div id="load"></div>` displays `2310`.

Or `myVariable=targ.id;` becomes `id=` of clicked element.

Here is code

```
function whichElement(e) {
var targ;
if (!e) {
var e=window.event;
}
if (e.target) {
targ=e.target;
}
else if (e.srcElement) {
targ=e.srcElement;
}
if (targ.nodeType==3) {// defeat Safari bug
targ = targ.parentNode;
}
myVariable=targ.id;
document.getElementById("load").innerHTML=myVariable;
}

<body id="-1" onmousedown="whichElement(event)">
<p id="3.14">click here to set variable to 3.14</p>
<h3 id="5">click here to set variable to 5</h3>
<p id ="2">click here to set variable to 2</p>
<p id ="2310">click here to set variable to 2310</p>
<div id="load"></div>
```

Need to get following behavior:

If click on `<p id ="2310">click here to set variable to 2310</p>`

then in `<div id="load"></div>` displays `click here to set variable to 2310`.

Or `myVariable=targ.id;` value is clicked text.

As understand need something like this

``var myVariable = $("#???clicked id????").text();`

But do not understand how to correctly implement it in code

Please advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
<body id="-1">

<p id="3.14">click here to set variable to 3.14</p>
<h3 id="5">click here to set variable to 5</h3>
<p id ="2">click here to set variable to 2</p>
<p id ="2310">click here to set variable to 2310</p>

<div id="load"></div>
```

JS:

```
document.body.onmousedown = whichElement;
var output = document.getElementById("load")
function whichElement(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var targ = e.target || e.srcElement;
    if (targ.nodeType===3) {// defeat Safari bug
        targ = targ.parentNode;
    }
    output.innerHTML = targ.innerHTML;
}
```

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/aGWGn/5/

Note: If I remember it well, in HTML5 an `id` can be what you want, but before HTML5 it should start with a letter, not number.