# With ajax and json send clicked text to php and get back php data in popup window

Tags: php, ajax, json

This code, if click on text inside `div class="example4DOMWindow"` sends defined values to php and then get back php data and in popup window displays data received from php.

Here is example http://jsfiddle.net/rigaconnect/q3RcV/1/

This is ajax that sends and receives data

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var one = $("#first_var").text();
    var two = $("#second_var").text();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '__popup-window_ajax.php',
        data: {var1: one, var2: two },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            $('#load').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

This part of code displays popup window (sample here http://swip.codylindley.com/DOMWindowDemo.html)

```
<body>

<div id="first_var" class="example4DOMWindow" style="width: 50px;">text one</div>
<div id="second_var" class="example4DOMWindow" style="width: 50px;">text two</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.example4DOMWindow').openDOMWindow({
        eventType:'click',
        windowSourceID:'#example4InlineContent',
    });

</script>
<div id="example4InlineContent" style="display:none">
    <div>
        <div id="load"></div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
```

And this is php file code

```
$p_one = $_POST['var1'];
$p_two = $_POST['var2'];
$test = $p_one. '<br>test<br>'. $p_two;
echo json_encode($test);
```

The code sends to `php` only `var` that is defined. Like `var one = $("#first_var").text();` So if no `var` inside `ajax` code, nothing send. And sends all `var`s.

Necessary the code to send to `php` only clicked text. User clicks on `text one`, sends `text one` and do not send `text two`; clicks on `text two`, sends only `text two`.

Here https://stackoverflow.com/a/17622947/2360831 / http://jsfiddle.net/aGWGn/5/
clicked text is passed as value to `javascript`.

Tried to put all together like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    document.body.onmousedown = whichElement;
    var output = document.getElementById("load")
    function whichElement(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        var targ = e.target || e.srcElement;
        if (targ.nodeType===3) {// defeat Safari bug
            targ = targ.parentNode;
        }
        output.innerHTML = targ.innerHTML;
    }
    //var one = $("#first_var").text();
    var one = targ;
    var two = $("#second_var").text();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '__popup-window_ajax.php',
        data: {var1: one, var2: two },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            $('#load').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

But the code does not pass `var one = targ;` to `php` file (`var two` also does not pass).

From my understanding the main question is how to pass `var targ` or `var output`(?) to `var one`....

Please, advice what is incorrect

**Update**

Changed `data` to `data: {var1: output, var2: two },`

and in popup window see

```
[object HTMLDivElement]
test
text two
text two
```

Changed to `var one = targ.innerHTML;` but does not work....

**Changes to get to work**

Changed `var output = document.getElementById("load")` to `var output = document.getElementById("load1")`

In html added `<div id="load1"></div>`

And changed

```
//var one = $("#first_var").text();
var one = targ;
var two = $("#second_var").text();
```

to `var one = $("#load1").text();`

Now seems work. But think the code need improvements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understand, you need to pass only the clicked text to php, right?

If so, you don't need all that code from the moment you are using jquery. You just need to attach a 'click' event handler to `.example4DOMWindow` and send only the text of the clicked div.

**index.html:**

```
<body>
<!--
<script src="jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.DOMWindow.js"></script>
-->
<div id="first_var" class="example4DOMWindow">text one</div>
<div id="second_var" class="example4DOMWindow">text two</div>

<div id="example4InlineContent" style="display:none">
   <div id="load"></div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.example4DOMWindow').openDOMWindow({
      eventType:'click',
      windowSourceID:'#example4InlineContent',
  });  

  $(".example4DOMWindow").on('click', function(event){
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '__popup-window_ajax.php',
      data: { 'clickedText' : $(this).text() },
      success: function(data) {
        $('#load').html(data);
      }
    });
  });

});
</script>

</body>
```

**__popup-window_ajax.php:**

```
<?php
$var = $_POST['clickedText'];
echo json_encode($var);
?>
```

Comment: Yes, only clicked text need to pass. Thanks, will experiment

Comment: This works. Only can not understand why in popup window text is inside `" "`. Expect `text one`, but see `"text one"`

Comment: This is because you are using `json_encode` in PHP, and is returning a json object instead of just a string. If you don't want that, just do `echo $var` or parse the response in javascript with `JSON.parse(data)`